# reloading from clojure file

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, ring

I'm new to clojure and I'm trying to wrap my head around live reload in in clojure I want to be able to monitor/ watch all/ any project file and update the browser automatically

So far I have the following

```
(defproject app2 "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write this!"
  :url "http://exampl.com/FIXME"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.9.89"]
                 [ring "1.5.0"]
                 [stasis "2.2.0"]
                 [hiccup "1.0.5"]
                 [clj-tagsoup "0.3.0"]
                 [optimus "0.18.5"]
                 [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.5.0"]
                 [cljs-ajax "0.5.8"]
                 [enfocus "2.1.1"]]
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.1.3"]
            [lein-ring "0.9.7"]]
  :cljsbuild {:builds [

    {:id "dev"
    :incremental true
    :source-paths ["src/cljs"]
                        :compiler {
                          :main "scripts.client"
                          :output-to "resources/public/js/main.js"
                          :output-dir "resources/public/js/out"
                          :asset-path "js/out"
                          }}]}
  :aliases {
    "start-dev" ["pdo" ["cljsbuild" "auto"] ["ring" "server-headless"]]
  }
  :source-paths ["src"]
  :resource-paths ["resources"]
  :main app2.server
  :repl-options {
                :prompt (fn [ns] (str "your command for <" ns ">, master? " ))
                :welcome (println "Welcome to the magical world of the repl!")
                :init-ns app2.hawk
                :init (app2.hawk/init)
                :caught clj-stacktrace.repl/pst+
                :skip-default-init false
                :host "0.0.0.0"
                :port 9000
                :timeout 40000
              }
  :ring {
    :init app2.hawk/init
    :handler app2.server/app
    :auto-reload? true :auto-refresh? true :reload-paths ["resources/public"]
    :refresh-paths ["resrouces/public"]
  }
  :profiles {
    :dev {
          :repl-options {
            :nrepl-middleware [cemerick.piggieback/wrap-cljs-repl]
          }
          :source-paths ["src"]
            :ring {
              :nrepl {
                :start? true
                :port 9000
                :host "0.0.0.0"
              }
            }
            :dependencies [
              [ring-refresh "0.1.1"]
              [http-kit "2.0.0"]
              [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.11"]
              [com.cemerick/piggieback "0.2.1"]
              [hawk "0.2.10"]
            ]
            :plugins [
              [lein-pdo "0.1.1"]
            ]
          }
        }
```

)

for my handler I have

```
(ns app2.server
  (:use [ring.middleware.resource :only [wrap-resource]]
        [ring.middleware.file-info :only [wrap-file-info]]
        [ring.middleware.file :only [wrap-file]]
        [ring.middleware.reload :refer [wrap-reload]]
        [ring.middleware.content-type :refer [wrap-content-type]]
        [ring.middleware.refresh :refer [wrap-refresh]]
        [ring.util.response :refer [file-response]]
       )

(defn wrap-utf-8
  "This function works around the fact that Ring simply chooses the default JVM
  encoding for the response encoding. This is not desirable, we always want to
  send UTF-8."
  [handler]
  (fn [request]
    (when-let [response (handler request)]
      (if (.contains (get-in response [:headers "Content-Type"]) ";")
        response
        (if (string? (:body response))
          (update-in response [:headers "Content-Type"] #(str % "; charset=utf-8"))
          response)))))


(defn handler [request]
            (file-response (:uri request) {:root "resources/public"}))

(def app (-> handler
             wrap-content-type
             wrap-reload
             wrap-refresh []
             wrap-utf-8))
```

And then I am running hawk from repl

```
(ns app2.hawk
(:require [hawk.core :as hawk])
(:require [app2.server :refer [export-pages]]))

(defn init
  []
  (export-pages)
  (hawk/watch! [{:paths ["src/app2/templates" "resources/templates"]
               :filter hawk/modified?
               :handler (fn [ctx e]
                          (export-pages) ;; i'm compiling html pages dynamically to the server root but how do I then notify browser than html has changed? can i force server to reload from here?
                          ctx)}]))
```

Comment: For regular clojure workflow, `lein test-refresh` is super useful:  https://github.com/jakemcc/lein-test-refresh

Comment: For ClojureScript, be sure to see `figwheel`: https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel

Comment: So fig wheel is the ONLY solution? not really in need of any "test" right now. I'm really just trying to learn some basics before i get into heavy frameworks

Comment: There are many tools, libraries, & frameworks for CLJS.  You may like https://github.com/magomimmo/modern-cljs or possible http://funcool.github.io/clojurescript-unraveled/ also.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using Boot instead of Leiningen, the [system](https://github.com/danielsz/system) project will give you all the reload goodness you can expect from a Lisp, with plenty of examples.

Be sure to check the [Holy Grail demo](https://github.com/danielsz/holygrail), which leverages system, to get started with minimal fuss.

Comment: I tried system 0.3.0-SNAPSHOT back before 0.3.0 was released, and it seemed to work pretty well to insert the Boot task like `(system :auto true)` into my task pipeline as a sort of "refresh" task. I didn't want to depend on a snapshot version, though, so I set it aside for a while. When I came back to it after 0.3.0 was released, I was no longer able to get the `system` task to work as a simple code reloader, which is why I published the [`boot-refresh`](https://github.com/samestep/boot-refresh) library. Are the reloading capabilities of system just meant to be more specialized for Component?

Comment: Nice, you wrote a wrapper for `tools.namespace`! Yes, `system` was designed to provide restarts in addition to code reloading, which it does by leveraging Component.

Comment: Right, I understand that. What I'm wondering is: it previously seemed to me that, although `system` is meant to be used with Component, it should also work as a task to simply reload code without Component; is that the case, or does it just not work to use `system` to reload code without Component? If the former, could you possibly add some documentation with a small demo that shows how to do that? I'm asking because I'm concerned that I simply wasn't using `system` correctly and `boot-refresh` doesn't actually satisfy any purpose that isn't already satisfied by `system`.

Comment: You were using `system` correctly, you raised a use case that I didn't anticipate and which you solved nicely with your `boot-refresh` task. However, I realized that accommodating your use case in `system` was trivial and desirable, so the latest SNAPSHOT version will do what you want. You will find a demo here: https://github.com/danielsz/no-restarts. Thank you!

Comment: All right, thanks! Glad to know that I wasn't missing anything. Thanks for adding that feature and demo; it'll certainly be useful to have. :)

Comment: Boot is something I had looked into and it was an alternative I wanted to try but I was already into a project and didn't want to start over. Integrating it was a bit too tedious at the time...will definitely try boot out in the future

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have put together a great setup so far. 
and for managing this workflow [Figwheel](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel) is the logical next step. If you are doing any Clojurescript + clojure-web stuff you almost certainly **should start with figwheel**, you will have a much more pleasant experience.

Comment: Maaannnn I've tried fig wheel twice and I'm so not comfortable with it...can't watch most of the project files. can't customise repl the way I want. still lacks some features in my opinion should be standard. Coming from a nodejs background it didn't measure up. but I'll give it a go once more.

Comment: Question do yo need to `lein figwheel` in order to use figwheel?or can you use it's api and "hook" it into your existing logic?

Comment: have to admit documentations are pretty vague and abrupt. Had for noobs